# compare file line by line python

Tags: python, list, compare

What is the most elegant way to go through a sorted list by it's first index? Input:

```
Meni22   xxxx xxxx
Meni32_2 xxxx xxxx
Meni32_2 xxxx xxxx
Meni45_1 xxxx xxxx
Meni45_1 xxxx xxxx
Meni45   xxxx xxxx
```

Is it to go trough line by line:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
for line in input:
    if line[0] not in list1:
    list.append(line)
else:
    list2.append(line)
```

Example won't obviously work. It adds the first match of the line[0] and continues. I would rather have it go through the list, add to list1 lines that it finds only once and rest to list2.

After script:

```
List1:

Meni22   xxxx xxxx
Meni45   xxxx xxxx

List2: 

Meni45_1 xxxx xxxx
Meni45_1 xxxx xxxx
Meni32_2 xxxx xxxx
Meni32_2 xxxx xxxx
```

Comment: Are those `xxxx xxxx` the same for every line that starts the same?

Comment: how many columns does your input have? Two or three?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. Based on the "After script" section, are you just wanting to split the input into two lists based on whether or not the first token contains an underscore?

Comment: @Wooble No they're different in every case.

Comment: @Aya No I don't wan't to split bt underscore. It was only accident they were now sorted like that.

Comment: @jamylak Does that matter if I just sort them by ind[0]? I have 2-4 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
lis1 = []
lis2 = []
with open("abc") as f:
    c = Counter(line.split()[0] for line in f)

for key,val in c.items():
    if val == 1:
        lis1.append(key)
    else:
        lis2.extend([key]*val)
print lis1
print lis2
```

**output:**

```
['Meni45', 'Meni22']
['Meni32_2', 'Meni32_2', 'Meni45_1', 'Meni45_1']
```

**Edit:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
lis1 = []
lis2 = []

with open("abc") as f:
    dic = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        spl =line.split()
        dic[spl[0]].append(spl[1:])

for key,val in dic.items():
    if len(val) == 1:
        lis1.append(key)
    else:
        lis2.append(key)
print lis1
print lis2

print dic["Meni32_2"]  #access columns related to any key from the the dict
```

**output:**

```
['Meni45', 'Meni22']
['Meni32_2', 'Meni45_1']
[['xxxx', 'xxxx'], ['xxxx', 'xxxx']]
```

Comment: Works nicely, but since we split here by [0] it drops the other columns from lists. That was not intended. Any way to solve this?

Comment: @jester112358 yes you can use `collections.defaultdict` in that case, see my updated solution.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You have been more than helpful already, but if you have the time and this is easy: If I want to edit the lists, what would be the easiest way? In this case: Fam_c355_1 ['7322', '3'] ['7344', '4'] I'd like to print something if the second value of the key is below x. Also: the list is really messy if I put it to excel, since I can't use "\n, \t" etc like with normal lists. What's the easiest way in here?

Comment: I guess I can split it to fit the excel.

Comment: @jester112358 you only want to print the second list? i.e `['7344','4']`

Comment: Fam_355_1 7322: 3  <-- value low
Fam_355_2 7442: 25 <-- value ok    This would be the final output I'm looking for.

Comment: @jester112358 you can compare the value : `if int(dic['Fam_355_1'][0][1])<some_value: print something`

Answer (score 3):

Since the file is sorted, you can use `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
list1, list2 = res = [], []
with open('file1.txt', 'rb') as fin:
    for k,g in groupby(fin, key=lambda x:x.partition(' ')[0]):
        g = list(g)
        res[len(g) > 1] += g
```

Or if you prefer this longer version

```
from itertools import groupby
list1, list2 = [], []
with open('file1.txt', 'rb') as fin:
    for k,g in groupby(fin, key=lambda x:x.partition(' ')[0]):
        g = list(g)
        if len(g) > 1:
            list2 += g
        else:
            list1 += g
```

Answer (score 1):

consider using [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

```
import difflib

d = difflib.Differ()
fa = open('a.txt'); fb = open('b.txt')

diff = d.compare("".join(fa.readlines()), "".join(fb.readlines()))
print ''.join(list(diff))

fa.close(); fb.close()
```